# Generate MFCC with good noise for an audio signal of 0.01 seconds

Tags: python, mfcc

I'm using 16000Hz, mono WAV files for my CNN project. Here is the code for MFCC generation

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np
signal, sr = librosa.load('test.wav', sr=None)
mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal[0:160], sr=16000, n_fft=160,
                                    n_mfcc=20, n_mels=50).T, axis=0)
```

The problem is when using this mfcc-based tensorflow model for testing and prediction, all the predictions are almost equal to 0.99. When using a larger input signal, e.g. y=signal[0:1600], the predictions are much better.

How do I generate good quality mfcc for an input signal of 0.01 seconds or signal[0:160]?

Is it possible to write a function that takes three parameters:
y, sr, and numpoints and generate the best possible mfcc by calculating the rest of the parameters automatically?

```py
def mfcc(y:array, sr:int, numpoints:int):
    # calculate params    
    return librosa.feature.mfcc(...)
```

Comment: if your signal is too short, it might not be able to represent what you want it to represent. Seeing the forest from the trees kind of thing.

Comment: Why are you doing the mean? That eliminates all temporal variation?

Comment: What is the purpose of your CNN system? What kind of sounds are you supposed to detect / discriminat between?